# Oracle PL/SQL: Returning specific selected columns from procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the best method for returning specific column values from a Procedure. For example, the below code doesn't work

```
/*DECLARATION*/
TYPE t_data IS TABLE OF Table1%ROWTYPE;

PROCEDURE get_values(data OUT t_data) AS    
  BEGIN    
    SELECT a.object_id, a.num, b.descrip
      BULK COLLECT INTO data
      FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN
           Table2 b ON (a.id = b.id)
     WHERE a.date IS NULL;                
  END get_values;
```

In the same scenario if I use a `SELECT *`, it works...

Comment: You've declared data as a table of records corresponding to table1.  Your select statement selects 2 columns from table1 and one from table2.

Comment: If you can do what you need in plain SQL, why do you need a procedure in the first place? (I ask because very often people use PL/SQL when there is no need to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is an exercise on how to use a procedure to get a list of structured values; I would never recommend such an approach to get data from a table, preferring, if possible, a pure SQL method.

You seem to have tables like these:

```
create table table1(id ,object_id, num, "date")  as (
    select 1, 1, 100, sysdate from dual union all
    select 2, 2, 200, null from dual
);
create table table2(id, descrip) as (
    select 1, 'desc1' from dual union all
    select 2, 'desc2' from dual
);
```

You're trying to create a procedure that return a set of rows, where each row contains elements from both tables; to do so, you need to build a type that matches the result of your select query.

You may want to define your package like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE yourPackage AS
    TYPE tRec IS RECORD /* made to match the columns you want to extract in your query */
    (
        object_id                               NUMBER,
        num                                     NUMBER,
        descrip                                 VARCHAR2(100)
    );

    TYPE tTab IS TABLE OF tRec;

    PROCEDURE get_values(data OUT tTab);
END yourPackage;
create or replace package body yourPackage as
PROCEDURE get_values(data OUT tTab) AS    
  BEGIN    
    SELECT a.object_id, a.num, b.descrip
      BULK COLLECT INTO data
      FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN
           Table2 b ON (a.id = b.id)
     WHERE a."date" IS NULL;                
  END get_values;
 end yourPackage ;
```

You can call the procedure in the package this way:

```
declare
    someVar yourPackage.tTab;
begin
    yourPackage.get_values(someVar);
    --
    if someVar.first is not null then
        for i in someVar.first .. someVar.last loop
            dbms_output.put_line(someVar(i).object_id || ' - ' || someVar(i).num || ' - ' || someVar(i).descrip);
        end loop;
    end if;
end;
```

and this is the result you get:

```
2 - 200 - desc2
```

Comment: Excellent. That was exactly what I was looking for Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you cannot create a `Type` of any `table%rowtype` outside a PLSQL block. You need to create table as `object` and then have to create a `type of that object`. Then you  can use it.

See below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Table11 AS OBJECT
(
   id NUMBER,
   num NUMBER,
   description VARCHAR2 (20)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_data IS TABLE OF Table11;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_values (v_data OUT t_data)
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT Table11 (a.row_id, 222, 'hello')
     BULK COLLECT INTO v_data
     FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b 
     ON (a.row_id = b.appid)
    WHERE a.date IS NULL;

END get_values;
```

execution:

```
DECLARE
   v_var   t_data;
BEGIN
   get_values (v_var);

   FOR i IN 1 .. v_var.COUNT
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_var (i).id ||'  ' ||v_var(i).num  ||'  ' || v_var(i).description );
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
1  222  hello
2  222  hello

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```